# build the application from unity 3d and it doesn't work to install on the andoid smartphone device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, sdk, augmented-reality

I have successfully built the apk on Unity, but when I install it on my smartphone "apk is not installed".

i have turned on minimum target API Android 7 Api level 24 nougat and target API Android 11 API LEVEL 30.
[player settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSU7N.png)

results when I try to install the application
[install apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBSEQ.jpg)

Comment: Do you have another app with the same application id installed? Try installing on a fresh emulator.

Comment: I have tried on various devices, the result is the same

Comment: Does the app signing work? Is the APK signed?

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but I'd enable Arm v7 and and set the Target API to Maximum installed (not sure of the actual setting name and my Unity is currently compressing some stuff).

Answer (score 1):

The question probably missing some context, but you can try this:

- Enable "Unknown Sources" in your device's security settings: Go to Settings > Security > Unknown Sources and enable it. This will allow you to install apps from outside the Google Play Store.
- Ensure that your device meets the minimum requirements for running the Unity-built APK
- Make sure the APK is properly signed
- Clear the cache and data of the Google Play Store app
- Try installing the APK on a different device